# Не могу получить содержимое XMLHttpRequest запроса

Tags: javascript, json, http, xmlhttprequest

Не могу понять как увидеть содержимое XMLHttpRequest POST запроса при передачи данных с клиентского js на серверный js.
Итак на стороне клиента в js файле создан XMLHttpRequest:

```
 eventDrop: (info)=>{
          var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
              path = "scheduler/eventDrop",
              updatedEvent = {
                "newStartDate": info.event._instance.range.start,
                "newEndDate": info.event._instance.range.end
              };
          request.open("POST", path, true);
          request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
          request.send(updatedEvent);
          console.log(info);
          console.log(updatedEvent);
        },
```

На стороне сервера запроса обрабатывается так:

```
router.post('/scheduler/eventDrop', (req,res)=>{
    var result = req.body;
    console.log(typeof(result));
    var data = JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log(typeof(data));
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.newStartDate);
});
```

Консоль показывает что `result` приходит в виде `object`, потом после `JSON.stringify(result)` превращается в `string`, выглядит это как пустые скобки `{}`, а запрос `console.log(data.newStartDate)` выдает `undefined`.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Как увидеть данные из запроса? Спасибо

//========Part 2================//
Совершенно уже запутался.
Итак пробую просто передать текст:
-на стороне клиента

```
eventDrop: (info)=>{
          var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
              path = "scheduler/eventDrop";
          request.open("POST", path, true);
          request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'text/plain');
          request.send('test');
        },
```

-на стороне сервера

```
router.post('/scheduler/eventDrop', (req,res)=>{
    var result = req.body;
    console.log(result);
    console.log(typeof(result));
});
```

И все равно в результате в консоли `{}` и тип `object`!!!!
Почему?!! Помогите пожалуйста.
p.s. А если меняешь `header` на `request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')` то в консоли приходит `{ test: '' }`
//==========Решение==================//
Нужно было добавить `app.use(bodyParser.json());` чтобы `body-parser` мог разбирать JSON при получении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам стоит передавать данные формой:

```
eventDrop: (info)=>{
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    let path = "scheduler/eventDrop",
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('newStartDate', info.event._instance.range.start);
    data.append('newEndDate', info.event._instance.range.end);
    request.open("POST", path, true);
    request.send(data);
},
```

Если из каких-то соображений хотите именно жсон, то используйте `get` и интегрируйте жсон-строку в запрос

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Сделал как вы сказали. `FormData()` создает документ (проверил с помощью `formData.getAll()`. Но на стороне сервера все равно не могу видеть данные. `var result = req.body; console.log(result); console.log(typeof(result));` пишет что это объект и представляет в виде `{}`. Пробовал разные методы работы с объектами `Object. entries()`, `Object.values()`, `Array.from()` результат везде пустые скобки `[]` И кстати, нужно указывать `request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'multipart/form-data')`? Спасибо

Comment: Если использую `request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')` то в консоли вот что `[ '"newStartDate"\r\n' +  '\r\n' +  'Tue Aug 04 2020 02:00:00 GMT-0500 (Центральная Америка, летнее время)\r\n' +  '------WebKitFormBoundaryAkYxGI1SUEWLGCbL\r\n' +  'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="newEndDate"\r\n' +   '\r\n' +   'Tue Aug 25 2020 02:00:00 GMT-0500 (Центральная Америка, летнее время)\r\n' +   '------WebKitFormBoundaryAkYxGI1SUEWLGCbL--\r\n' ]` То есть данные все таки передаются но вот как их обработать?

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл добавить про бекенд. Для парсинга формы стоит использовать специальный модуль. Если будут файлы ещё высылаться, то лучше `formidable` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable), если планируются только обычные текстовые поля, то достаточно `body-parser` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

Comment: Я использую body-parser. Но все равно не могу прочесть результат запроса! Тут какая то фундаметальная простая ошибка и я не могу понять какая. Я добавил в вопрос еще информации.

Comment: Сверьтесь с документацией - проверьте, что вы правильно используете body-parser. Я не вижу, например, третьего аргумента между урлом и колбеком в обработке post-а - непосредственно самого экземпляра парсера.

Comment: Точно!!!! Нужно было добавить `app.use(bodyParser.json());` чтобы он джейсоны разбирал! У меня только `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));` был указан. Спасибо!